# How to make "Market Depth" chart in Plotly/Python?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm currently trying to make a market depth chart like the one on BitMEX here (not enough rep to post images yet): https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/53675680/85238644-5311e180-b3fd-11ea-9865-94e3451f335c.png

```
import pandas as pd
from bitmex_websocket import BitMEXWebsocket
```

```
ws = BitMEXWebsocket(endpoint="https://testnet.bitmex.com/api/v1", symbol='XBTUSD', api_key=None, api_secret=None)
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ws.market_depth())
df.head()


symbol  id  side    size    price
0   XBTUSD  15500000000 Sell    1003    1000000.0
1   XBTUSD  15500000100 Sell    100001  999999.0
2   XBTUSD  15502119900 Sell    5000    978801.0
3   XBTUSD  15504648350 Sell    2191000 953516.5
4   XBTUSD  15515440800 Sell    300 845592.0
```

```
# ommitted fuction that gets current bitcoin price for sake of brevity
def get_current_price(symbol):
    pass
current_price = request_history(symbol='XBTUSD', interval_mins=1, load_periods=1)['close'].iloc[0]
print(current_price)

Output: 9301.5
```

```
lower_bound = current_price * 0.99
upper_bound = current_price * 1.01
df = df.loc[(df.price > lower_bound) & (df.price < upper_bound)]
```

```
df.plot(kind='line', x='price', y='size')
```

My graph looks like this: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/53675680/85238728-f8c55080-b3fd-11ea-95b3-1b35c3b958f6.png

I think the first step would be bucketing the prices and then displaying them as a bar chart but I'm not quite sure. Any ideas on how I would go about creating a graph that looks more like the one on BitMEX, preferably using plotly? Thanks.

## EDIT

I've made some progress but still not close to matching what's on BitMex.

```
bins=[n for n in range(int(lower_bound), int(upper_bound), 10)]

lower_df = df.loc[df.price < current_price].price
upper_df = df.loc[df.price > current_price].price

plt.hist([lower_df, upper_df], bins=bins, edgecolor="k", color=['red', 'green'])
plt.xticks(bins[::5])  # display every 5th tick on x-axis
plt.show()
```

Image of Output: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/53675680/85241059-7d1cd100-b408-11ea-8b2b-f39997767419.png

```
groups = df.groupby([pd.cut(df.price, bins)])['size'].sum()
groups.plot(kind='bar')
```

Image of Output: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/53675680/85241076-902fa100-b408-11ea-941d-226927acb946.png

Comment: Here is a lot of documentation for histogram charts: https://plotly.com/python/histograms/

Answer (score 0):

I coded a library to get Binance data to show you: https://github.com/nand0san/binpan_studio

**Getting some data**

```
import binpan

data = binpan.Symbol(symbol='btcusdt',
                     tick_interval='5m',
                     time_zone='UTC')

data.get_orderbook()

    Price          Quantity Side

0      21068.06    0.00267  ask
1      21068.03    0.00387  ask
2      21068.00    0.00125  ask
3      21067.86    0.00827  ask
4      21067.59    0.01355  ask
... ... ... ...
9995    19395.19    0.01007 bid
9996    19395.10    0.00729 bid
9997    19395.06    0.00112 bid
9998    19394.98    0.00688 bid
9999    19394.80    0.00241 bid
```

**And plotting**

```
data.plot_orderbook()
```

[image]

The function used with plotly is:

```
def orderbook_depth(df: pd.DataFrame,
                    accumulated=True,
                    title='Depth orderbook plot',
                    height=500,
                    plot_y="Quantity",
                    **kwargs):

    ob = df.copy(deep=True)
    if accumulated:
        c_asks = ob[ob['Side'] == 'ask']['Quantity'][::-1].cumsum()
        c_bids = ob[ob['Side'] == 'bid']['Quantity'].cumsum()
        cumulated = pd.concat([c_asks, c_bids])
        ob.loc[:, 'Accumulated'] = cumulated
        plot_y = 'Accumulated'

    fig = px.line(ob, x="Price", y=plot_y, color='Side', height=height, title=title, **kwargs)
    fig.show()
```